# How to Convert Extended ASCII to HTML Entity Names in Python?

Tags: python, html, encoding, ascii

I'm currently doing this to replace extended-ascii characters with their HTML-entity-number equivalents:

```
s.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
```

What I would like to do is convert to the HTML-entity-name equivalent (i.e. `&copy;` instead of `&#169;`).  This small program below shows what I'm trying to do that is failing. Is there a way to do this, aside from doing a find/replace?

```
#coding=latin-1

def convertEntities(s):
    return s.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')

ok = 'ascii: !@#$%^&*()<>'
not_ok = u'extended-ascii: ©®°±¼'

ok_expected = ok
not_ok_expected = u'extended-ascii: &copy;&reg;&deg;&plusmn;&frac14;'

ok_2 = convertEntities(ok)
not_ok_2 = convertEntities(not_ok)

if ok_2 == ok_expected:
    print 'ascii worked'
else:
    print 'ascii failed: "%s"' % ok_2

if not_ok_2 == not_ok_expected:
    print 'extended-ascii worked'
else:
    print 'extended-ascii failed: "%s"' % not_ok_2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** This is the solution I'm going with, with a small fix to check that entitydefs contains a mapping for the character we have.

```
def convertEntities(s):
    return ''.join([getEntity(c) for c in s])

def getEntity(c):
    ord_c = ord(c)
    if ord_c > 127 and ord_c in htmlentitydefs.codepoint2name:
        return "&%s;" % htmlentitydefs.codepoint2name[ord_c]
    return c
```

Answer (score 2):

**edit**

Others have mentioned the `htmlentitydefs` that I never knew about. It would work with my code this way:

```
from htmlentitydefs import entitydefs as symbols

for tag, val in symbols.iteritems():
   mystr = mystr.replace("&{0};".format(tag), val)
```

And that should work.

Comment: That's why I said "aside from a find/replace", in other words, I don't want to build a dictionary of 128 characters. This solution would work for the code I posted though

Comment: Well I just adapted my code to use `htmlentitydefs` that others have mentioned. Now you don't have to build it :)

Comment: looks better... might need to add some checking for ASCII codes, since I don't want "<" to get replaced with `&lt;`

Comment: `entitydefs.get('<', False)` => `False` - it's only a one way replacement: `for e in entitydefs: print e` to see all the tags.

Answer (score 2):

Is `htmlentitydefs` what you want?

```
import htmlentitydefs
htmlentitydefs.codepoint2name.get(ord(c),c)
```

Comment: yes that is what I'm looking for.... not quite there yet though. I think I have a solution based on this

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how directly but I think the `htmlentitydefs` module will be of use. An example can be found [here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/594350-convert-unicode-chars-html-entities).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you don't want the conversion to be reversible? Your `ok_expected` string indicates you don't want existing `&` characters escaped, so the conversion will be one way. The code below assumes that `&` should be escaped, but just remove the `cgi.escape` if you really don't want that.

Anyway, I'd combine your original approach with a regular expression substitution: do the encoding as before and then just fix up the numeric entities. That way you don't end up mapping every single character through your getEntity function.

```
#coding=latin-1
import cgi
import re
import htmlentitydefs

def replace_entity(match):
    c = int(match.group(1))
    name = htmlentitydefs.codepoint2name.get(c, None)
    if name:
        return "&%s;" % name
    return match.group(0)

def convertEntities(s):
    s = cgi.escape(s) # Remove if you want ok_expected to pass!
    s = s.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
    s = re.sub("&#([0-9]+);", replace_entity, s)
    return s

ok = 'ascii: !@#$%^&*()<>'
not_ok = u'extended-ascii: ©®°±¼'

ok_expected = ok
not_ok_expected = u'extended-ascii: &copy;&reg;&deg;&plusmn;&frac14;'

ok_2 = convertEntities(ok)
not_ok_2 = convertEntities(not_ok)

if ok_2 == ok_expected:
    print 'ascii worked'
else:
    print 'ascii failed: "%s"' % ok_2

if not_ok_2 == not_ok_expected:
    print 'extended-ascii worked'
else:
    print 'extended-ascii failed: "%s"' % not_ok_2
```